# Initial value of @@ROWCOUNT varies across databases and servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, rowcount

We are attempting to run the a `DELETE` statement inside a `WHILE` loop (to avoid large transaction logs for lots of rows) as follows:

```
WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        DELETE TOP (250000)
        FROM
            MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
        WHERE
            MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.DATE_KEY = 20160301
    END
```

When this command is executed inside a new SQL Server Management Studio connection in our *development* environment, it deletes rows in blocks of 250K, which is the expected behavior.

When this command is executed in the same way on our *test* server, we get the message

```
Command completed successfully
```

That is, the `WHILE` loop was not entered when the statement was run.

After some additional investigation, we have found that the behavior also varies depending on the database that we connect to.  So if the code is run (in our *test* environment) while SQL Server Management Studio is connected to `MYDATABASE`, the `DELETE` statement does not run.  If we run the code while connected to `SOME_OTHER_DATABASE`, it does.

We partially suspect that the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` is not reliable, and may be different for different connections.  But when we run the code multiple times for each database & server combination, we see behavior that is 100% consistent.  So random initial values of `@@ROWCOUNT` do not appear to explain things.

Any suggestions as to what could be going on here?  Thanks for your help!

**Edit #1**

For those asking about the initial value of `@@ROWCOUNT` and where it is coming from, we're not sure.  But in some cases `@@ROWCOUNT` is definitely being initialized to some value above zero, as the code works on a fresh connection as-is.

**Edit #2**

For those proposing the declaration of our own variable, for our particular application we are executing SQL commands via a programming language wrapper which only allows for the execution of one statement at a time (i.e., one semicolon).

We have previously tried to establish the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` by executing one delete statement prior to the loop:

Statement #1:

```
DELETE TOP (250000)
FROM
    MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
WHERE
    MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.DATE_KEY = 20160301
```

Statement #2 (`@@ROWCOUNT` is presumably now 250,000):

```
WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        DELETE TOP (250000)
        FROM
            MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
        WHERE
            MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.DATE_KEY = 20160301
    END
```

However, whatever is causing `@@ROWCOUNT` to take on a different value on start-up is also affecting the value *between commands*.  So in some cases the second statement never executes.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a variable before you have set its value.  That is equally true for system variables.

The code that you have is very dangerous.  Someone could add something like `SELECT 'Here I am in the loop'` after the `delete` and it will break.

A better approach?  Use your own variable:

```
DELCARE @RC int;
WHILE (@RC > 0 OR @RC IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        DELETE TOP (250000)
        FROM MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
        WHERE MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.DATE_KEY = 20160301;

        SET @RC = @@ROWCOUNT;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your initial `@@ROWCOUNT` from?  I mean, you're never going to enter that block, because `@@ROWCOUNT` would be expected to be zero, so you'd never enter the loop.  Also, deleting in 250K batches wouldn't change the size of your transaction log - all of the deletions will be logged if you're logging, so there's no benefit (and some penalty) for doing this w/in a loop.

Comment: My impression is that the transaction log is cleared after each `BEGIN` ... `END` block.  What approach would you suggest for a lower overhead delete statement involving tens of millions of records?

Comment: Nope.  The transaction log is kept so that you can build upon a complete backup.  Doing a full backup tells SQL Server that you've got a new starting point, so it can empty out that transaction log.  If you don't *want* the transactions, you could `truncate log` but ... not such a great idea, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Have you traced the session?  Since `@@ROWCOUNT` returns the number of rows affected by the prior statement in the session, I would guess that either the last query SSMS executes as part of establishing the session returns a different number of rows in the two environments or that you have a login trigger in one or the other environments whose last statement returns a different number of rows.  Either way, a trace should tell you exactly why the behavior is different.

Fundamentally, though, it makes no sense to refer to `@@ROWCOUNT` before you run the statement that you are interested in getting a count for.  It's easy enough to fix this using a variable

```
DECLARE cnt integer = -1;
WHILE (cnt != 0)
BEGIN
  DELETE TOP (250000)
    FROM MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
   WHERE MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.DATE_KEY = 20160301;
  SET cnt = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```